# Istio mtls misconfiguration causes inconsistent behavior

Tags: kubernetes, tls1.2, istio, mtls

I have deployed 2 `istio` enabled services on a GKE cluster.

`istio` version is `1.1.5` and GKE is on `v1.15.9-gke.24`

`istio` has been installed with `global.mtls.enabled=true`

`serviceA` communicates properly

`serviceB` apparently has TLS related issues.

I spin up a non-`istio` enabled deployment just for testing and exec into this test pod to `curl` these 2 service endpoints.

```
/ # curl -v serviceA
* Rebuilt URL to: serviceA/
*   Trying 10.8.61.75...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to serviceA (10.8.61.75) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: serviceA
> User-Agent: curl/7.57.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 130
< server: istio-envoy
< date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 09:45:32 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
< x-envoy-decorator-operation: serviceA.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local:80/*
<
{"application":"Flask-Docker Container"}
* Connection #0 to host serviceA left intact


/ # curl -v serviceB
* Rebuilt URL to: serviceB/
*   Trying 10.8.58.228...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to serviceB (10.8.58.228) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: serviceB
> User-Agent: curl/7.57.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Execing into the `envoy` proxy of the problematic service and turning trace level logging on, I see this error

```
serviceB-758bc87dcf-jzjgj istio-proxy [2020-04-24 13:15:21.180][29][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:168] [C1484] handshake error: 1
serviceB-758bc87dcf-jzjgj istio-proxy [2020-04-24 13:15:21.180][29][debug][connection] [external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:201] [C1484] TLS error: 268435612:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HTTP_REQUEST
```

The envoy sidecars of **both** containers, display similar information when debugging their certificates.

I verify this by execing into both `istio` containers, cd-ing to `/etc/certs/..data` and running

```
openssl x509 -in root-cert.pem -noout -text
```

The two `root-cert.pem` are identical!

Since those 2 istio proxies have exactly the same tls configuration in terms of certs, why this cryptic SSL error on `serviceB`?

FWIW `serviceB` communicates with a non-istio enabled `postgres` service.

Could that be causing the issue?

`curling` the **container** of `serviceB` from within itself however, returns a healthy response.

Comment: Could you help put the yaml of your service? And please help give any information on how you configure the authentication policy of istio. Check the link here for similar issue https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14963

Comment: I have filed a detailed [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23422) on GH. Please note that I cannot/won't change the `mtls` policy to PERMISSIVE. It needs to remain in STRICT mode.